# Curl of an electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, conductors

> Which of these may be representing electrostatic field lines?
> [image: ]]

Why is option 2 incorrect? is it because the curl of an electric field should be zero and the figure violates the fact? Or is there some other possible reason?

Comment: I have cropped your picture and written the question in text, this helps people to find the question when they google it @Soura Deep . I think option-2 looks ok to me. I guess it **could** be wrong because there is no field by the charge on the leftward direction

Comment: Option 1 doesn't convince me though, shouldn't there be no field lines outside of the sheet?

Comment: @KarimChahine I think you are remembering it backwards, if the charge were outside the metallic sheet there would be no field lines inside it. When the charge is inside, the field lines do radiate out (since there is a net charge inside, any closed surface encapsulating the metallic sheet must have field lines leaving it as dictated by Gauss' law)

Comment: What does this have to do with the curl of the electric field? Option 2 looks good, apart from the fact that there should be also lines extending in the direction opposite to the plate.

Comment: @JakobKS You're right, thanks!

Comment: Option 1 is wrong because the field lines should meet the surface of the metal along the normal.  The lines inside the sphere do not satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 2):

The field for option two can be drawn with the [method of image charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges), Which look like

[image]